# Django bulk update for many to many relationship

Tags: django

I have and Event and EventCategory model with a many-to-many relationship.

There are 2 event categories - past (ID of 2) and future (ID of 1).

I want to find all Events in the future via

```
models = Event.objects.filter(categories__slug='future')
```

And then update them so they are all in the past.

Should I create a list of the Event instances, then delete from the related table, and insert the instances with the new category ID - just wanted some guidance if possible, on the most efficient way to do this.

Many thanks

Comment: you can use `update(**kwargs)` as you can read here https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/ref/models/querysets/#update

Comment: Many thanks for getting back. Yes, I'm using update(**kwargs) in my code, but I want to update the related table, not the main table and the docs say you can't do this "The update() method is applied instantly, and the only restriction on the QuerySet that is updated is that it can only update columns in the model’s main table, not on related models"

Comment: but you can rethink you current query and you can go to your goal table in another way for example as the documentation says:

`Entry.objects.update(blog__name='foo') # Won't work!`
but this will
`Entry.objects.filter(blog__id=1).update(comments_on=True)`

Comment: Many thanks for your comment - sorry for the delay - will take a look when I get a moment.

Comment: Hi, thanks for getting back. Still not sure how this will allow me to update the related table ... this obviously doesnt work Event.objects.filter(categories__id=1).update(categories__id=2) .. how do I update (effectively) the eventcategory_id in the related table from this? Sorry! I have posted my own solution below but I'm sure it can be improved on.

Answer (score -1):

I am not sure if this is the most efficient solution for my needs but it works:

Find the new category I want to associate to the events (this is the "past" category)

```
cat = EventCategory.objects.get(pk=2)
```

Here are my existing relationships, where 1 is the ID of the future category

```
models = Event.objects.filter(categories__id=1)

for model in models:
    model.categories.clear()
    model.categories.add(cat)
```

Now all of the entires in the related table are in the past category.

Comment: Whats your solution then